# What are these white rings in the Undead parish?

Tags: dark-souls

So I've just started my second playthrough on Dark Souls Remastered for the Xbox 360. Rang both bells and beaten Sif. I was returning from firelink and killed the Balder knights as usual when I noticed these two rings. They reappear and disappear at different angles:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HnVW.jpg]

I can't interact with them in any way so I wanted to know if anyone else had encountered these before? Is it a glitch or intentional design?

Comment: As an aside, I noticed the Drake Sword. Just in case you don't know about the weak scaling... [Why the Drake Sword sucks](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=164830419)

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Ties/b?ie=UTF8&node=507844

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are [Resonance Rings](https://darksouls.fandom.com/wiki/Resonance_Ring#targetText=Resonance%20rings%20appear%20as%20small,appear%20over%20the%20selected%20miracle.):

> Resonance Rings appear in an area where another player has recently used a miracle.  It is possible to find multiple Resonace Rings at once. Resonance rings appear as small white rings fixed slightly above the ground. When the player is close to one, the power of certain Miracles is boosted. When the player is close enough so that their miracles can receive a boost, a white circle will appear over the selected miracle.